# Embedding video on Wordpress from URL

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a wordpress gaming site where I wish to embed videos. I wish to embed them using URL's.. EG: This video:

```
https://xboxclips.com/EGGY+BREAD+1/a880ece5-e801-4a2e-928e-2f4f28c9ce2f
```

I want displaying on this page: https://www.onelastgo.com/fortnite-videos/

You will see what I'm trying to do if you click the link. However, on mobiles, you can only see the left side of the video unless you scroll across. Is there and easy way to set something to 100% so that it displays 100% of the screen width ? This is what I have so far..

```
<iframe src="https://xboxclips.com/EGGY%20BREAD%201/a880ece5-e801-4a2e-928e-2f4f28c9ce2f/embed" width="100%" height="400px" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"><span data-mce-type="bookmark" style="display: inline-block; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0;" class="mce_SELRES_start">﻿</span></iframe>
```

I have tried a few plug ins but none of them support the gaming clip URL. If I upload it to YouTube there's probably some nice YouTube plug ins but I thought a simple embed would be handy as I will need to keep changing the clips overtime.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Use css and set the `width`and the `max-width` of this `iframe` to 100% in the mobile media query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Not sure how to do that.. I have just started with wordpress. Where would I set this please?

Comment: You can use customizer to add css if you wanted to

Comment: You can do this multiple ways. There are plugins that will allow you to add CSS which might be easiest for you. You can add a function to functions.php or you can use the wordpress customizer https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/